# Cannot install Apache Flex SDK 4.11

Tags: apache, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, sdk

I tried to install Apache Flex SDK 4.11 to my Flash builder 4.7. I downloaded the installer from http://flex.apache.org/installer.html and installed the installer.

Then, I run the installer, the first page let me choose Flex, AIR, and player version. On the next page, it ask me to select folder to install. I tried to select "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64 Bit)\sdks" or even any other folder, and it stuck there. I cannot click on "Next" button. When I mouse over the field, it says "Invalid Flex SDK directory selected".

How can I get Flex SDK to be installed? Is there any alternative or manual way to do it? What is the valid directory should I select?

Thank you.

Comment: You could always build it from the source yourself; but it is a bit complicated.  Are you on a Windows machine?  If so, have you tried running the installer as an Administrator?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the directory you chose requires admin access. Either run the installer as administrator, or install to a different location, like C:\FlexSDKs or something.

Answer (score 3):

The Installer expects an empty directory.   So  just create a dir for 4.11 and point to it in the Installer.